# Не могу загрузить в Bitmap массив больше 10-ти картинок

Tags: android, массивы, bitmap

Создаю массив с размерностью 20 и пытаюсь заполнить его картинками, но больше 10-ти не получается залить. Такая ситуация со всеми известными мне видами массивов. Суть вопроса - одна картинка весит от силы 80 кб, а LogCat в Эклипсе ругается на то что кэша не хватает (32мб). Вообще цель загрузить в массив 50 Bitmap-ов вес которых всего 4,5Мб, а он мне выкидывает что при загрузке уже 20-ти кэш переполнен(32Мб).Как он может быть переполнен, если 20 картинок весят 1,65 Мб. Я чего-то не понимаю либо еще не знаю? Подскажите.
Вот часть кода(проблемного) на нем вылетает программа:

```
          private void massiv(){

           int y;
           int i=0;

           Bitmap bubbles;
           String mas;

           Bitmap[] bit;        
           bit = new Bitmap[20];

           while(i<20){
      mas=("a"+i);
      y =context.getResources().getIdentifier(mas, "drawable", "artik.BitmapMassiv");
        bubbles = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),y);   
        bubbles = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bubbles, 500, 500, true);
        bit[i] = bubbles;
        i++; 
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть ли у изображений альфа-канал? Если нет, тогда вы точно можете уменьшить объём нужной памяти  в 2 раза. Дело в том, что при декодировании ресурса все битмапы автоматически переводятся в Config.ARGB_8888, но если у вас нет альфа-канала, тогда зачем вам декодировать альфа конфигом? Я делал вот так:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, op);
```

При декодировании изображения 200х200 конфигом `ARGB_8888` потребляется памяти: `200*200*4=160000` байт
А если использовать `RGB_565`, то `200*200*2=80000` байт

Answer (score 5):

Вы ведь понимаете, что размер распакованной битовой матрицы графического формата с компрессией (jpg, png) может превышать размер непосредственно файла в 6-20 раз? Таким образом, ваши "от силы 80 кб" при распаковке с лёгкостью могут занимать более одного Мб в памяти.

Comment: Вот этого я как раз не понимал т.е. не знал. Спасибо за ответ. Как тогда можно реализовать это, если это возможно?

Comment: Полагаю, вам нужно пересмотреть сам способ решения задачи. Расскажите, что вы хотите сделать в итоге (то есть, зачем вам понадобилось таким образом загружать кучу битмапов), и, возможно, совместными усилиями мы найдём подходящее решение.

Comment: Я хочу сделать что-то вроде гиф изображения, но управляемого: время паузы между выводом картинок, очередность картинок - прямое и обратное, и в конце концов останов вывода на любом из битмапов. Можно конечно в цикле на прямую загружать во время итерации, но работает медленно(вывод изображения подтормаживает). Вывод - нужно загрузить поближе(я имею в виду кэш) чтоб быстрей выводить изображение на канве. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Comment: А если сделать одну картинку с высотой, равной высоте исходных картинок, а шириной, равной ширине одной картинки, помноженной на количество кадров. Получится этакий кэш. Нужный кадр просто копируется на своё место из этой полосы. Думаю это займёт меньше времени на вывод.